# How do I shut of camera/scanner in react-native-qrcode-scanner?

Tags: react-native, qr-code

Current code:

```
import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';
function ScanScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
      <QRCodeScanner reactivate={true} reactivateTimeout={3000}
        onRead={data => navigation.navigate('Third', {target:data.data})}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

It works, but here's what I want to do:
The user can navigate between screens, one of them being a QR code scanner.
While scanning, I need to debounce the scanner so it doesn't keep generating onRead events. The user could 
a) start a scan in the scan screen without reading a QR code and navigate manually to another screen.
b) read a QR and automatically move to another screen for processing, then go back to scan again.
For this reason I need to re-enable the scanner after some reasonable time.
I can't just set reactivate to false because then the QR scanner is inactive until I restart the app.
The problem is that when the user stays in Another screen, the QR scanner re-activates after the timeout and tries to scan when it is not desired. What I ideally would like to do is to deactivate the QR scanner while the user is not in the scan screen, and re-activate it with the above mentioned parameters whenever the user enters the scan screen.
Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: what u can do is put QRCodeScanner in a modal when onRead is called close the modal, so it will read the data only once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had almost the same problem. The scanner does not stop scanning while showing another View (using `reactivate={true}`). I am using react-navigation and so I came up to following solution.

You can listen on what is happening with your view with `focus` and `blur`.

```
this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    this.setState({viewFocused: true});
});

this.props.navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
    this.setState({viewFocused: false});
});
```

Note: you place this piece of code in `componentDidMount` or using `React.useEffect`.

Based on the state `viewFocused` you can render the QR Code Scanner.

```
this.state.viewFocused && (
    <QRCodeScanner
        onRead={onRead}
        reactivate={true}
        reactivateTimeout={2000}
    /> );
```

This helps me to solve my problem. To not scan while showing other views but to scan if the view is shown again. Credits to 
[pkyeck on github.com](https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner/issues/136#issuecomment-423190383)

Answer (score 2):

as explained in the doc, you can do it progammatically

```
  <QRCodeScanner
      onRead={this.onSuccess}
      ref={(node) => { this.scanner = node }}  <-- add this
    />
```

and in your method (for example, in Alert or onPress button), reactivate the scanner like this:

```
 onPress: () => {
      this.scanner.reactivate()
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

With React hooks:

```
let scanner = useRef(null);

<QRCodeScanner
onRead={onSuccess}
ref={node => { scanner = node;}}
/>
```

Then you can attach it to a button. For example:

```
onPress={() => scanner.reactivate()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, Re-rendering screen with the useIsFocused hook.

[React Navigation useIsFocused](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#re-rendering-screen-with-the-useisfocused-hook)

```
import {useIsFocused} from '@react-navigation/native';

const ScannerCamera = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const viewFocused = useIsFocused();

  return (
    viewFocused && (
      <QRCodeScanner
        containerStyle={{height: SCREEN_HEIGHT}}
        cameraStyle={[{height: SCREEN_HEIGHT}]}
        showMarker={true}
        onRead={onSuccess}
        flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto}
      />
    )
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Same thing as mentioned above in functional component or using hooks**

`import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';`

```
const ScannerCamera = ({navigation, route}) => {
  let uuId = null;
  const [viewFocused, setViewFocused] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onFocus = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      setViewFocused(true);
    });

    const onBlur = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      setViewFocused(false);
    });

    return {onFocus, onBlur};
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    viewFocused && (
      <QRCodeScanner
        containerStyle={{height: SCREEN_HEIGHT}}
        cameraStyle={[{height: SCREEN_HEIGHT}]}
        showMarker={true}
        onRead={onSuccess}
        flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto}
      />
    )
  );
};
```